# Working with Idempotent elements of a Ring Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $R, S$ be rings with unities $1_R$ and $1_S$ respectively, and let $\theta \colon R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. Prove that $\theta(1_R)^2 = \theta(1_R)$. And if $1_S$ and $0_S$ are the only idempotents of $S$, and $\theta$ is not the zero homomorphism, prove that $\theta(3_R) = 3_S$, where $3_S = 1_S + 1_S + 1_S$.

Comment: With what exactly are you having problems? For example, can you show that $\theta(1)^2=\theta(1)$?

Answer (score 2):

From the other part, note that because $\theta$ is a ring homomorphism then:

$$\theta(1_R)^2=\theta(1_R)\cdot\theta(1_R)=\theta(1_R^2)=\theta(1_R)$$

For the other part, the problem says that $\theta$ is a non-zero ring homomorphism AND tAAVQhe only units of $S$ are $1_S$ and $0_S$. Note from this that $\theta(1_R)$ is an unit of $S$ because of the first part, so the only values could take $\theta(1_R)$ are $0_S$ or $1_S$. If $\theta(1_R)=0_S$, the ring homomorphism would be the zero homomorphism (contradiction to the hypothesis), so $\theta(1_R)=1_S$, then: 
$$\theta(3_R)=\theta(1_R+1_R+1_R)=\theta(1_R)+\theta(1_R)+\theta(1_R)=1_S+1_S+1_S=3_S$$

The reason of why the ring homomorphism would be the zero homomorphism if $\theta(1_R)=0_S$ is because if you consider any element $x\in R$, 
$$\theta(r)=\theta(1\cdot r)=\theta(1)\cdot\theta(r)=0_S\theta(r)=0_S$$

So any element evaluated in $\theta$ will let you the $0_S$ if $\theta(1_R)=0_S$

Comment: In all likelyhood, the OP's definition of ring homomorphism does not include that condition (if it does, the problem simply does not make a lot of sense…)

Comment: But when it is a ring homomorphism between non zero rings both with unity it must happen that $\theta(1_R)=1_S$, don't? (can you say me what means OP please?)

Comment: (The OP is the original poster, that is, the person who asked the question)

Comment: It is not uncommon to define ring homomorphisms without including the condition that $1$ be mapped to $1$, even if the domain and codomain do have unit elements. The map $x\in\mathbb Z\mapsto(x,0)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is an example of a nonzero map of rings, both having units, which does not respect the units.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. I will try to fix it without it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez does it's correct now? I would be pleased if you check it.

Comment: For the second part, you need to argue somehow, starting from the hypothesis that $\theta$ is not the zero homomorphism, that $\theta(1)=1$. You used this but did not prove it.

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to correct that part. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, now is complete.

Comment: It would be surely helpful to explain exactly why the ring homomorphism would be the zero homomorphism if the image of 1 is 0

Comment: Ok, added the explanation about it too :-)

Comment: Great! :-D ${}{}$